# Mi tema de wordpress no se ve completo en mi hosting premium

Tags: wordpress-theme

hice mi primer tema en Wordpress, al subirle a mi hosting en hostinger.mx no se ve completo, esto fue lo que hice:

1-"Instalación rápida" de Wordpress que recomienda hostinger.

2-Luego descarge mi base de datos local y la exporte a la base de datos previamente creada en mi domio de hostinger.

3-Elimine todo lo que había en la carpeta de wp-content en el servidor y subí todo lo que yo tenía de wp-content en local.

4-Por ultimo, el archivo de wp-config.php lo modifique y edite le puse el nombre de la base de datos, el usuario y la contraseña.

Resultado:

Al poner mi tema en mi escritorio de wordpress y meterme a mi dominio, se ve mi tema pero solo el html, css y una imagen que tenía, pero todo lo que lleva php y demás (vaya, lo dinámico) no se ve nada, ya llevo 3 días y no mas no encuentro una solución.

P.D

Note que cuando hago una instalación de wordpress y modifico el archivo wp-config.php y me meto a mi sitio, se tiene que volver a crear una cuenta de usuario y password, por curioso me metí a ver la base de datos que uso y se elimino y wordpress puso una suya.

Answer (score 1):

Encontre la respuesta, es la siguiente:
Resulta que en el archivo wp-config.php la variable $table_prefix era distinta en mi servidor que en el local, solo puse la misma que en local y listo.

Comment: ¿Por que no me dieron puntos por resolver mi propia duda? =(

Comment: Porque tienes que aceptarla :D Click en el check verde del costado

Answer (score 0):

nunca he publicado nada aun en un servidor online, pero siempre en el localhost he tenido que configurar algunas variables de como la memoria y otras boberia, no sera que necesites ponerte en contacto con el administrador del hosting para estas cosas.

Comment: Esto parece realmente un comentario mas que una respuesta. Con un poco mas de reputación, [vas a poder comentar en cualquier lado.](//es.stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment). Por favor mira [answer]